# jupyter-notebook: add css class to output cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to add a class to the output cell using cell magic? For example:

```
In [1]: %%css-class highlight
        display(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3,4)))
```

and then the the cell `Out [1]` will have the class "highlight" so that I can change the format using css.

Comment: untested: `display('html code to start div with class'); display(data); display('html code that closes the div')`

Comment: this one does not work. Each `display` call is to be wrapped in a separate `<div class='output_subarea'>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some search, I found this approach:

First we import:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
```

Then in some cell:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), list('ABC'), list('abcdefgh'))
display(x)
display(x)
Javascript('this.element.attr("id", "myoutput")')
```

The `this.element` in `javascript` points to the `<div class="output">` for the current cell; and `this` points to the `OutputArea` instance (see 'static/notebook/js/outputarea.js')

Then we can manipulate this output `<div>`

```
%%javascript
$('#myoutput').toggleClass('horizontal')
```

using css

```
%%HTML
<style>
.horizontal {flex-direction: row}
</style>
```